# Deterministic seeded shuffle

Tags: functions, random

How can I find an injective function $f$ so that mapping that function over each element of the ordered sequence $[1\cdots{n}]$, yields a deterministic shuffle (random permutation) that is "good" enough to be considered pseudo-random?

What operations can I perform or repeat in the definition of $f$ in order to achieve better "entropy".

In the definition of $f$ we can use a $s$ (seed) constant number and $n$.

Comment: How good is good enough?  What tests of randomness do you want it to pass?  What kind of definition of $f$ would you allow?

Comment: @RobertIsrael That if any one sees the list of generated numbers cannot guess the pattern with which it was generated. As far as the definition of ƒ, any definition that is calculable in constant time is good enough for me.

Comment: Depending on interpretation, that criterion is either too subjective or impossible.